# Javascript - Count of characters in a textfield returning NaN

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form I am trying to do, where if some one inputs text in a text field of a form, then clicks submit, I want to show him the cost of the sign (charactercount x price) i keep getting `NaN`!

Heres my Html:

```
<section class="sign" id="sign">
<h3 class="sign_header">CUSTOM SIGNAGE</h3>
<p class="sign_text">Enter Name, the cost per letter is $<span id="lettercost">6</span>.</p>
<form class="info_form">
  <input type="text" id="inputletters" value="Example Name"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" id="getprice"  onClick="getPrice();">
</form>
```

and here is my Javascript

```
function getPrice(){
    var quantity = document.getElementById('inputletters').value.length;
    var price = document.getElementById('lettercost');
    var total = quantity*price;
    var cost = document.getElementById('cost');
    cost.textContent = total;
}
```

Comment: You have to parse them as integers! Also, `price` isn't even a string containing a number, it's an element. Did you want the `value`?

Comment: `price` is an HTMLElement ... what do you expect the result of a multiplication would be ... you need to use  `var price = document.getElementById('lettercost').textContent;` - no need to parse it if you use multiplication

Comment: Jarmouda X .textContent; worked flawlessly! I cannot believe it was such a tiny yet stupid mistake! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a runnable example -- `price` was an object, you want `.textContent`, and parse those into numbers for this to work.

```js
function getPrice() {
  var quantity = document.getElementById('inputletters').value.length;
  var price = document.getElementById('lettercost').textContent;
  console.log(typeof quantity, typeof price)
  var total = Number(quantity) * Number(price);
  var cost = document.getElementById('cost');
  cost.textContent = total;
}
```

```html
<section class="sign" id="sign">
  <h3 class="sign_header">CUSTOM SIGNAGE</h3>
  <p class="sign_text">Enter Name, the cost per letter is $<span id="lettercost">6</span>.</p>
  <form class="info_form">
    <input type="text" id="inputletters" value="Example Name"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" id="getprice" onClick="getPrice();">
  </form>
  <div id="cost"></div>
</section>
```